# When Odo was sent out as part of the 100 from the Great Link, what gave him amnesia?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

[We know](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Odo) that Odo was one of the 100 changelings sent out by the Founders to explore the galaxy.

We know Odo was found adrift in his natural gelatinous state in the Denorios belt in the Bajoran system.

We know Dr Mol did experiments on him not knowing he was a sentient being.

By the events of series 1 - [the pilot episode,  Emissary](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/402.txt) - Odo is looking for answers:

> Major, I was found in the Denorios  Belt.  I don't know where I came from... no idea if there are any others like me. All my life, I've been forced to pass myself off as one of you...  always wondering who I really am. The answers to a lot of my questions may be somewhere on the other side of that wormhole.

So it seems that Odo travelled a long way, and lost memory of his mission.

My question is: **when Odo was sent out as part of the 100 from the Great Link, what gave him amnesia?**

Comment: It's worth noting that the other changeling from the 100 (Laas) also has no memory of his origin - so Odo is not unique.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "[one hundred](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hundred_Changelings)" weren't amnesiac, they were simply very young.

> **FEMALE SHAPE-SHIFTER:** *Because even in our solitude we desired to learn more about the galaxy.  You were one of a hundred "infants" we
> sent off to gain that knowledge for us.*
>
> **ODO:** *But how could you be sure we'd find our way back here?*
>
> **FEMALE SHAPE-SHIFTER:** *You had no choice.  The urge to return home was implanted in your genetic makeup.* - <sub><sup>[The Search, Part II](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/448.txt)</sup></sub>

The goal was apparently to see how the various species in the galaxy at large would treat harmless changeling infants (and presumably to gain tactical knowledge of their technology and defences).